Resources on understanding cryptographic concepts
I'm new to cryptography and confused on those concepts like adversaries, challengers, security definitions, security assumptions, threat models, etc.
I tried many things to figure them out, including reading some papers on MPC but just found didn't know what they were trying to do.
To me, everything seems making sense in some degree but still obfuscated. Like, w.r.t a proof trying to say something is "indistinguishable", I can understand what is every step trying to do. But from a broader perspective, why do we do the whole thing? How is it becoming secure? What's the relationship between this proof and a real-world security?
Hence, I'm wondering if there's any way help me understand what they're doing?

Hello, @maplepicker. I would recommend that you start understanding the fundamentals of cryptography. I recommend that you study Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell's Introduction to Modern Cryptography. There are alternative textbooks and lecture notes for courses available, but I prefer this one. Once you've mastered the fundamentals and want to focus on MPC, I recommend starting with How To Simulate It - A Tutorial on the Simulation Proof Technique by Yehuda Lindell. Best wishes.

Thank you for the recommendation. I saw this book somewhere else, as well. I think I'll give it a try!

Book recommendations and open questions such as these are considered off topic (even though helpful users will often post something in the comments :) )

@MaartenBodewes Thank you for the reminding! I just got here :)
